# On long press context menu (floating menu) not getting call when registerForContextMenu(photoViewAttacher.getImageView())?

Tags: android, contextmenu

ImageView attached to PhotoViewAttacher. But as I have used it in PhotoViewAttacher, OnLong press onCreateContextMenu() not getting called.

```
photoViewAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView);
registerForContextMenu(photoViewAttacher.getImageView());

imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.placeholder));

photoViewAttacher.update();

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
            MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}
```

How it will work?

Comment: The possible reason for this maybe your imageview is not receiving touchevent as they maybe either be consumed by overlaying view or parentview, or you may have overridden onlongpress of imageview. So please give us more information about your view hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I just checked what PhotoViewAttacher is. For showing contextmenu you will have to do this

```
photoViewAttacher.setOnLongClickListener(myLongClickListener);
```

And in onLongClick method of myLongClickListener call `openContextMenu(photoViewAttacher.getImageView())`

Hope that helps.